# Smooth spline curve with cscvn in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, spline

I am facing the following dilemma.

["Natural" or periodic interpolating cubic spline curve (`cscvn`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cscvn.html) allows me to fit an interpolating spline curve that passes all the control points. However, in my problem the data points are noisy, so an interpolating spline curve has many zig-zags.

[image]

So I thought maybe I need an approximating (instead of interpolating) spline curve that doesn't necessarily pass through all the points. Then I came across [cubic smoothing spline (`csaps`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/csaps.html).

[image]

Now the curve is indeed smoother, but it has problems when I have multiple y values around an x value. So the fitting result is not really "correct".

How do I have a smooth and "correct" fitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take the maximum von the y values and that's it.

Or if you believe that the noisy end is correct you should enlarge the bin size (variable bin size). This will lead to a good spline but the curve will drop.

It depends on what you believe is correct. In anyway enlarging the bin size also in the "smooth" part of  the curve (<200) should improve the smoothness of the spline.

Comment: Thanks. The end part is correct, so I can't take the maximum of the y values. About the bin size, is this a parameter of `csaps`? I don't quite get it

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, I don't see why it works? Even if I enlarge the bin size, at the curve end, when x goes from a small value to a large one, the curve still "oscillates" in y. Am I missing anything?

Comment: If you enlarge the bin size to the "wavelength" (or larger) of the oscillation you won't see the oscillation anymore. The curve is lowered and should lie in the middle of upper and lower band of the spline, where you have two y values. - 
If you enlarge the bin size in lower x value range you will get a smoother curve because you enlarge the statistic.